# Tasks in Eclipse not Going Away

Tags: eclipse

I just set up Eclipse for PHP Developers on a new machine, and now I have a problem I haven't experienced before.

Normally, I keep track of short-term work that I want to do by adding TODOs in comments on a file.  These show up on the right side of the editing window as little blue rectangles.  This helps me find the next thing I need to work on.

That part is working, but when I remove the comment the blue rectangles aren't going away.  I have used Eclipse for years and never had this problem before.

Anyone know why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

For tasks added in the source file's syntax, you often need to Clean and Build the project again to reprocess the file (those are handled in the relevant compiler). For ones that don't get "compiled", check the General->Editors->Structured Text Editors->Task Tags page and have it try to redetect them from there.